# Outlook Macro to add signature to email body

Tags: html, vba, outlook, macros, mailto

I am facing this problem, suppose i have a html anchor like this

```html
<a href="mailto:?subject=subject&body=some text here">Send Email</a>
```

if you open the link above using outlook the body overrides the signature in outlook.

my question is, can outlook macros append the signature after the message body? and if so, is there vba code sample to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

No, you will need to use Outlook Object Model for that - display the message first (signature will be added at that point), then add your own body.